# Redux const { var1, var2 } = this.props;

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I am new to react js. I am working on a project and found this line

```
 const { var1, var2 } = this.props;
```

Props which are comming in this component are

```
type PropsType = {
  var1: Array<any>,
  a: Array<any>,
  b: boolean,
  c: boolean,
  var2: (string) => void,
  d: () => void,
  e: () => void
};
```

I am confused. What it means?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

Comment: This is [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring). It's not got anything to do with React, it's a new language feature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
const { var1, var2 } = this.props;
// the same as
// const var1 = this.props.var1;
// const var2 = this.props.var2;
```

Here are the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) ?

Comment: Can you explain what happens with other props. that means they are assigned to any one to var1 or var2 or they remain un assigned .

Comment: They are stayed available just in `props` object.

Answer (score 7):

Well redundant information, but a revision for me. :)
Anyways to start with, this is destructuring object assignment. What this means is that, this is a shorthand way to get the object properties' value from an object(such as this.props in here). 
So when you want to extract a property named 'var1' and 'var2' from the 'this.props', by writing the instruction -

```
const { var1, var2 } = this.props;
```

you ask for the property named 'var1' and 'var2' from 'this.props' to be stored in constants 'var1' and 'var2'. All other properties are simply ignored. And if any of the asked property names are not there, they are simply given 'unassigned' value.

After this, you may consider going through more details(magic of it!) here - 
 [MDN - object_destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly related to React nor Redux. It is ES6 [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) assignment.

It means that you're assigning `this.props.var1` and `this.props.var2` to consts `var1` and `var2` respectively.